# Password-protecting all worksheets in Excel on open regardless of name?

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to protect all worksheets with a password while retaining outlining options. I have this code set to run when the workbook is opened:

```
 Option Explicit   
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()
            Dim ws As Worksheet
            For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            With ws
                .Protect "password1", , , , True
                .EnableOutlining = True
                .Protect Contents:=True, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
            End With
        End Sub
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work - some sheets remain unprotected after I open the workbook. I have another VBA method that goes through and hardcode references the worksheet tab names individually:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
With Sheets("Instructions Worksheet")
        .Protect "password1", , , , True
        .EnableOutlining = True
    End With
```

This code works, but I'd like to avoid this - if a tab is renamed then you get a runtime error. How do I successfully reference and password protect all worksheets when opening the workbook, without hardcoding? What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you sure you have the `Workbook_Open()` under the `ThisWorkbook` object in the VBA editor?  And where is the `Next` clause for the `For Each` loop?

Comment: @chancea Yes, I have 'Workbook_Open()' under the 'ThisWorkbook' in the editor. I did forget the 'Next' - I'm a novice with VBA. Should that be placed after the 'End With'? What would the 'Next' look like?

Comment: Yeah after the `End With` place a `Next ws`

Comment: Thanks! It works. If you want you could repost your comments as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad it worked, I posted that as the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBA `For` loops need to be closed with a `Next` statement using the variable name.

So in your code you have

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
```

That needs to be closed with a

```
Next ws
```

The full code would look like:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            .Protect "password1", , , , True
            .EnableOutlining = True
            .Protect Contents:=True, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```